# Unity Scene was crashed in android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

I have working AR-App in unity and android using google arcore sdk.I have a AR scene with 100 models and also i have initial scene in that initial scene script i was load the AR Scene because of splitting  expansion files for android.When i was load the AR Scene from initial scene the app was crashed.I don't know how to fix the issue and also i can't find any error message in unity.Is large number of models in a scene was a issue?

Initially i have 40 models its worked fine but i was increased the model 40 to 100 its getting crashed.

Comment: I'm also face the same issue when loading large number of models load in unity project and export. Import to Android studio the scene was crashen when the model size reach greater than 1.5 GB.

Comment: I think your out of memory

Comment: my obb size is 1.02gb is there any limitation in obb file size unity?